# Open vpn LAN routing. Mind blown

Tags: routing, openvpn

I have a problem with routing fromn vpn network to lan(and back also).
Server OS Windows Server 2012(all firewalls down for testing), client OS Windows 7.
Enabled ip forwarding on the server, added static routes to server.ovpn, added static routes to LAN.
From my LAN I can ping vpn server (192.168.0.246, and also on his vpn address 10.5.0.1). 
From vpn network client (any) I can ping vpn server (10.5.0.1, and also on his lan address 192.168.0.246)
VPN clients can ping and access any network resourses in 10.5.0.0\24.
But cant go any further. So if anyone can give me a hint, that would be sweet.

```
port 1194

proto udp

dev tun

ca C:\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\ca.crt
cert C:\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\OVPN.crt
key C:\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\OVPN.key  # This file should be kept secret

dh C:\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\dh1024.pem

topology subnet

server 10.5.0.0 255.255.255.0

ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 10.5.0.0 255.255.255.0"


push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.0.249"
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.0.251"

push "dhcp-option DOMAIN *.local"
push "dhcp-option SEARCH *.local"

client-to-client

keepalive 10 120

tls-auth C:\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\ta.key 0 # This file is secret

cipher AES-256-CBC

persist-key
persist-tun

status openvpn-status.log

verb 3
```

Server log is way too big to paste it here so here ot goes http://pastebin.com/5zBBw2ad

Client config

```
client

dev tun

proto udp

remote here was address 1194

resolv-retry infinite

nobind

persist-key
persist-tun

ca C:\\Openvpn\\ssl\\ca.crt
cert C:\\Openvpn\\ssl\\SharanMTS.crt
key C:\\Openvpn\\ssl\\SharanMTS.key

remote-cert-tls server

tls-auth C:\\Openvpn\\ssl\\ta.key 1

cipher AES-256-CBC

verb 3
```

Client log here http://pastebin.com/VUbZN84Y

My route print

```
0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.0.10 192.168.0.77 20
10.5.0.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.246 192.168.0.77 21
127.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 On-link 127.0.0.1 306
127.0.0.1 255.255.255.255 On-link 127.0.0.1 306
127.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 On-link 127.0.0.1 306
192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0 On-link 192.168.0.77 276
192.168.0.77 255.255.255.255 On-link 192.168.0.77 276
192.168.0.255 255.255.255.255 On-link 192.168.0.77 276
224.0.0.0 240.0.0.0 On-link 127.0.0.1 306
224.0.0.0 240.0.0.0 On-link 192.168.0.77 276
255.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 On-link 127.0.0.1 306
255.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 On-link 192.168.0.77 276
```

client route print

```
0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.3 276
10.5.0.0 255.255.255.0 10.5.0.1 10.5.0.49 20
10.5.0.49 255.255.255.255 On-link 10.5.0.49 276
127.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 On-link 127.0.0.1 306
127.0.0.1 255.255.255.255 On-link 127.0.0.1 306
127.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 On-link 127.0.0.1 306
192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0 10.5.0.1 10.5.0.49 20
192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 On-link 192.168.1.3 276
192.168.1.3 255.255.255.255 On-link 192.168.1.3 276
192.168.1.255 255.255.255.255 On-link 192.168.1.3 276
224.0.0.0 240.0.0.0 On-link 127.0.0.1 306
224.0.0.0 240.0.0.0 On-link 192.168.1.3 276
224.0.0.0 240.0.0.0 On-link 10.5.0.49 276
255.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 On-link 127.0.0.1 306
255.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 On-link 192.168.1.3 276
255.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 On-link 10.5.0.49 276
```

Server route print

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.0.10    192.168.0.246     10
         10.5.0.0    255.255.255.0    192.168.0.246    192.168.0.246     11
         10.5.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link          10.5.0.1    276
         10.5.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.5.0.1    276
       10.5.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.5.0.1    276
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.0.246    266
    192.168.0.246  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.246    266
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.246    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link          10.5.0.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.0.246    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.5.0.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.246    266
===========================================================================
```

Comment: Consider adding a little graphic to visualize your network setup and what works and doesn't work. It could help a ton. From what I understand you're having trouble to connect to resources that use LAN (`192.168`) addresses from your VPN (`10.5`) clients? Do you refer to the server as `My route` or is that your client on the LAN?

Comment: Yes i want to have a possibility to use shares, printers etc on my local 192.168.x.x from vpn subnet. Clients are all across my local area, have different white ip on Internet and same subnet in their LAN()192.168.1.1. As i understand something is wrong with connecting this 2 subnets on the vpn server(192.168.0.246 on LAN 10.5.0.1 on VPN subnet). Adding a bridge doesnt make a trick.

Comment: Why would you not include the route output for the central component if you suspect that it's at fault?

Comment: Added route print from server. As i see no route between 10.5 and 192.168. Thats an epic facepalm for me.

Comment: Thank a lot! OMG, sometimes its useful to have a nice kick from someone. Well now i must close question or mark its as solved?

Comment: You could write an answer to your own question (possibly including a small information on how you fixed the route and what showed you that there wasn't a route defined) and accept it or, if you're reluctant to do so, you could just leave it alone/delete it etc.

Comment: You could write an answer to your own question (possibly including a small information on how you fixed the route and what showed you that there wasn't a route defined) and accept it or, if you're reluctant to do so, you could just leave it alone/delete it etc.

Answer (score 0):

With help of some smart man, I saw that I havent provided route between my VPN subnet and LAN network. So on my server I added static routes from one subnet to another
route -p add 10.5.0.0/24 192.168.0.246
and
route -p add 192.168.0.0/24 10.5.0.1
So now a can have acces to both networks.
Thx to https://superuser.com/users/619267/seth